# how to fixed a div col-10 in right and right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to fix a div on the right but it is causing a problem i tried position:absolute top:0 right:0 but it doesn't work and content is start showing on navbar

```html
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
        integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #025;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="{% url 'users:home' %}" style="font-size: 25px; font-weight:600;">
                <img src="{% static 'images/apple-icon.png' %}" class="d-inline-block align-text-center"
                  style="margin-left: 50px; height: 40px;">
                Digi Dash
              </a>
            </div>
              {% else %}
                <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:login' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary text-white" style="border-radius: 10px;">Log In</button></a>
                </div>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </nav> 
          #side nav-bar
          <div class="container-fluid h-100">
            <div class="row h-100">
                <div class="col-2" id="side-nav" style="position:fixed">
                    <h4><img src="{{ user.profile.profile_pic.url }}" alt=""
                            style="max-width: 150px; max-height:150px; border-radius: 50%;"> <br>
                          <span> Hi <strong
                            style="color: #B9C04C; cursor:default;"> {{ user.username }}</strong></span>
                        <p></p></h4>
      
                    <!-- Navigation links in sidebar-->
                    <a class="text-center side-link text-white" href="#"><iconify-icon icon="material-symbols:dashboard"></iconify-icon> DashBoard</a><br />
                    <br />
                    <a class="text-center side-link text-white" href="#">My Order</a><br />
                    <br />
                    <a class="text-center side-link text-white" href=""><iconify-icon icon="solar:moon-fog-bold"></iconify-icon> Dark Mode</a><br />
                    <br />
                    <a class="text-center side-link text-white" href="#">My Address</a><br />
                    <br />
                    <hr>

                </div>
                <div class="col-10" style="position:sticky; right:0;">
        <div class='col-sm-12' url-endpoint='{% url "users:api_data" %}'>
            <div class='col-sm-5' style="float: left;">
                <canvas id="myChart2" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-5' style="float: left;">
                <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
            </div>
            <div class='col-sm-5' style="float: left;">
                <canvas id="myChart3" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
            </div>
            </div>
```

basically, my navbar and side navbar are fixed All I want is to fix  on right and an element scroll like youtube adding a image for better understanding i also tried ml-auto in the same tag

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code for this:

```
{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   height:100vh;
}
```

position fixed will fix the div to it's position and it doesn't go anywhere with scrolling. using vh for your height will cause your container to arrange it's size based on the size of the screen.

Comment: .col-10{
       position:fixed;
       right:0;
       overflow:scroll;
    }

Comment: top 0 will move the container on top which will hide the navbar

Comment: That's the reason I define height in the code. With a proper position nothing will be hided, top 0 sets the starting location of your element at the top of your screen, nothing else